# ui.position.left not working with css margin: 0 auto

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to build a *scrollable menu* that should use margin: `0 auto`;

Below is my *codepen* where it is **working** fine **because I didn't use** `css margin: 0 auto` (refer css panel `.wrap` class).

But this has two issues:

1. It is not scrolling end to end - *Codepen url*: [codepen.io/VK009/pen/PRKmNP](http://codepen.io/VK009/pen/PRKmNP)
2. While using `margin: 0 auto;` in `.wrap` and it's stops working properly because of `ui.offset.left`- *Codepen url*:- [codepen.io/VK009/pen/yKobVP](http://codepen.io/VK009/pen/yKobVP)

How can I make the menu use *margin*: `0 auto` and *scroll end to end*.

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS on this ID. Hope this will work.

```css
#nav_main{
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Hello Raydoan, I don't want to use horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ui.offset` instead of `ui.position`...The idea is  here to drag the element using the difference between the parent width and child width...

```js
var parentPos = $('.samNan').offset();
var parentWidth = $('.samNan').outerWidth();
var childWidth = $('.wrap').outerWidth();
var diff = parentWidth - childWidth;
$(".wrap").draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.offset.left <= parentPos.left && ui.offset.left >= diff + parentPos.left) {
      ui.offset.left = parentPos.left;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  scroll: false,
  axis: "x"
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.samNan {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrap {
  background: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

#nav_main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav_main li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav_main li a {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<div class="samNan">
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul id="nav_main">
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 8</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 9</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 10</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 11</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 12</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 13</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 14</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#">Menu 15</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bhuwan, it's working ! One more thing can you make it compatible with iphone and android phone, currently it not working with mobile touch.

Comment: @Amanverma for mobile support you will need to use [**jQuery UI Touch Punch**](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)...Updated..!